# ASP.NET mocking Membership.GetUser with Moles framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moles

Here is a method that returns a view model with user information:

```
    public ActionResult EditUserInfo(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
            var model = new UserEditorViewModel
                            {
                                UserName = userName,
                                EmailAddress = user.Email
                            };
            return View(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

How can I unit test it using Moles framework? There is a method `MMembership.CreateUserStringString()` but I couldn't figure out how to implement it to fake user identity.

Comment: It's bad practice to use static methods. They are difficult to unit test in isolation.

Comment: What are you trying to unit test?  Unless you're building a membership provider, you shouldn't be unit testing that class's methods.

Comment: I am trying to test different scenarios, for example if I pass a user name of a non-existent user.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I think OP is asking how to mock the `Membership.GetUser` call.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `Membership.GetUser` is a static method and I'm trying to mock it with moles framework.

Comment: Hmm.... As part of your unit test prep, ensure a user exists or does not exist... or you can build a membership provider expressly for setting expectations, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a solution. I had to add moles assembly for `System.Web.ApplicationServices` to be able to mock `MembershipUser`. The final test method loks like this:

```cs
    [TestMethod, HostType("Moles")]
    public void EditUserInfoTest()
    {  
        var testUserName = "TestUser";
        var controller = new UserEditorController();
        using (MolesContext.Create())
        {
            var user = new MMembershipUser
            {
                UserNameGet = () => "TestUser",
                EmailGet = () => "test@test.test"
            };        
            MMembership.GetUserString = (userName) =>
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(testUserName, userName);
                return user;
            };
            var result = (ViewResult)controller.Edit(testUserName);                
            Assert.AreNotEqual("Error", result.ViewName);
        }
    }
```